# Find function of mongodb does not work as it expeted, in other hand the shell works

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have got a collection in a mongodb called "docs" but I cannot access to the itmes. I put manually the document ids.

I followed the official documentation and the code is the same:

```
var mongodb_connection_string = "mongodb://localhost:27017/docsdb";

mongo_client.connect(mongo_client.connection_string, function(err, db) {

   var docs_collection = db.collection('docs');

   var cur = docs_collection.find(); // cur is undefined after this

   while (cur.hasNext()) {
      var el = cut.next();
      console.log(el);
   }

});
```

The bucle never ends and the var el is undefined. Thus, when I call "count()" the nodejs says me "undefined".

Although, I cannot do this:

```
db.docs.find().forEach(function(x){
                        self.log(x);
                    });
```

Nodejs says me: `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"`

**UPDATE**

Connecting using shell works:

```
mongo docsdb
db.docs.find()

... all the items are listed ...
```

Entries:

```
{"_id":"go_b0de007d-4f00-683f-c9df-2a982940e316","source":"...","location":"..."}
{"_id":"go_4ca1a326-98ca-7703-70d8-b4923cb8ad0e","source":"...","location":"..."}
{"_id":"go_7677775c-2509-33be-6f8d-1830af4adf48","source":"...","location":"..."}
{"_id":"go_4f85798c-073a-e4a0-09a4-05e6bffce488","source":"...","location":"..."}
{"_id":"go_b1eaed92-3989-076a-a32d-09e6f64a0fd4","source":"...","location":"..."}
{"_id":"go_e85c643d-4766-8649-8e56-c2e2c4b6795f","source":"...","location":"..."}
```

Comment: Can you please show me database entries!!

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database ? In node.js you are connecting to `docsdb` whereas you are connecting to `mydb` in the shell. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Jaco No the database name is ok, it was a mistake, updated

Comment: @dlopezgonzalez: did you try my code?

Comment: @SoniPandey yes, I did, look the comment on your awnser.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongodb_connection_string = "mongodb://localhost:27017/docsdb";

mongo_client.connect(mongodb_connection_string, function(err, db) {

   var docs_collection = db.collections('docs');
   var cur = docs_collection.find(); // cur is undefined after this

   while (cur.hasNext()) {
      var el = cut.next();
      console.log(el);
   }

});
```

try with this

Comment: db.docs returns undefined. I can only take the collection using "db.collections([NAME])"

Comment: so you are getting data, in your question you defined docs_collection before mongo connection?

Comment: You are writing mongo_client.connection_string, in place of this you should write mongodb_connection_string

Comment: I fixed,, no, the docs_collection is created on the mongodb callback.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I need to use the callback to retrieve the result:

```
             my_collection.findOne( { _id: "lb_352233" } 
                                         ,function(err, item)
                                         {
                                             ...
                                         });
```